# No funciona la transición de mobile menú sin abrir a mobile menu abierto

Tags: css, animación

Siento que es muy "Agresivo" cuando se abre ya que no tiene ninguna animacion, trate de animarlo poniéndole una id para que se desvanezca pero no creo que sea la forma ya que evidentemente no funciona, me gustaría poder hacer que vaya apareciendo el menu del costado y se qeu eso no es difícil de hacer pero el problema es que no se agregar dicha animación con el toggle de javascript, esto se hacerlo con CSS pero esta forma de agregar el menu a la pagina me descoloco la verdad ya que estoy aprendiendo.

Muchas gracias por las respuestas.

```js
function toggleMobileMenu(menu) {
    menu.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
.open .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-6px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-6px, 6px);
}

.open .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.open .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-6px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-6px, -8px);
}




#hamburger-icon {
  margin: auto 0;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hamburger-icon div {
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: #CC9544;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.open .mobile-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color:#1C0A00;;

    

}

#transition{
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}



.mobile-menu { 
    display: none; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 11.3vh; 
    left: 0;
 height:100vh;
 width: 100%;

}

.mobile-menu li {

  margin-bottom: 10px;
}


  

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  header nav {
    display: none;
  }

  #hamburger-icon {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
    <header >
        <div class="Headu">
         <div id="hamburger-icon" onclick="toggleMobileMenu(this)">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
        <ul class="mobile-menu" id="transition">
          <li><a href="/home" class="Link">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="/products" class="Link">Products</a></li>
          <li><a href="/about" class="Link">About</a></li>
          <li id="login"><a href="/login" class="Link" >Login</a></li>
          <li id="signup"><a href="/signup" class="Link">Signup</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>
```